# Postfix. User outgoing e-mail restriction

Tags: postfix

Is there a way to configure Postfix to restrict outgoing e-mail per user so that he/she can ONLY send e-mails to one specific e-mail address?

For example: username@mydomain.com where username is actually user login.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is a policy service such as postfwd or policyd; postfix does not natively have very good 1:1 rules.

Comment: yeap... thanks... i did a little digging and i think its doable.. policyd has strange documentation :/ when i come up with solution ill post it here

Answer (score 0):

It does look as if it is possible, the following documentation from the postfix website will give you a nudge in the right direction

[Postfix sending restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)

Comment: yea... i've been there but still can't find solution.. to put it more simple.. i need some kind of restriction or mapping per single user. For example: user1@example.com to be allowed to send messages only to: user1@newdomain.com. Thats it. This user (group of users in future) is not allowed to send messages to example.com domain or anywhere else.